# Crop geotiff with bounding box

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

In a project using gdal I need to crop a geotiff file with a bounding box in pixel or coordinates epsg:4326. The cropping of large images works fine.

The next step is to manage cases where the image is smaller than the bounding box. The idea here is to avoid getting blank data.

When I crop my geotiff using the gdal_translate tools with `-srcwin` or `-projwin` an error occurs when the size of the bounding box is bigger than the geotiff size.

When I crop my geotiff using the gdalwarp tools with `-te xmin ymin xmax ymax`, my result get the size of the bounding box even if this one is bigger.

What could be the "average" of those two behaviours? Just to fit my result to the interception of the bbox and the geotiff file?

My process makes part of a .NET Project so I could do it into my code using .NET but is there a way or an option in gdal to do it?

I found documentation about the ogr2ogr command `-clipsrc` but it doesn't manage geotiff file.

Comment: I have the same need but I do not know how to do it...
is there a way to do this?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96706)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/96706)